# Create <select> type dropdown using web components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

The  html element needs  child elements. The select itself isn't really useful unless there are the option elements. I want to be doing to same thing.

If I create a web component and it looks like this

```
<my-select>
  <my-option> one </my-option>
  <my-option> two </my-option>
  <my-option> three </my-option>
</my-select>
```

My aim in general here is that the option tags **shouldn't be put in a slot**. They are needed to define data for rendering the select. So at the very least they would need to be moved into the shadow DOM. But that seems like the wrong thing to do.

Another example of this sort of thing would be  and

. If the  was a custom element you wouldn't want to put the

into slots.  is another example.

Ok here is a concrete example. Given the  markup above, the my-select web component will actually create a shadow DOM and render a  instead. So the my-select needs to look at all the  elements inside it and create an

for each one.

So how the heck do I do that? I must be missing something right?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<my-select>
  <my-option> one </my-option>
  <my-option> two </my-option>
  <my-option> three </my-option>
</my-select>
```

If you have attached a *shadowDOM* and you want to **move** this *lightDOM* to *shadowDOM* you can use:

```js
connectedCallback(){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    this.shadowRoot.append(...this.children);
  }
}
```

The `setTimeout` is required because the `connectedCallback` fires on the **opening** tag, the lightDOM at that time is not parsed yet.
You have to wait for all lightDOM to be parsed, `setTimeout` makes sure you execute the code at the first opportunity (when the Event Loop is empty).

For Event Loop details see: https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-event-loop-3dif

Comment: Thanks for you reply. In the case of a <select> (my example) the <my-option> tags aren't needed for rendering. They are data tags. Therefore it doesn't make sense to move them to the shadow DOM.

Comment: You can't read them until that lightdom is parsed